# Efficient access to last value in large list in python

Tags: performance, list, python-3.x

I am using a large list in my python script and need to access the last value of this list very often, while the list doesn't change that much. Should I simply access it directly (`longList[-1]`) or is it preferable to assign the last value of the list to a variable (`lastValue = longList[-1]`) and use this variable instead. Of course I have to update the variable when the list changes.

From a functionality point of few it is the same, I am more concerned about the performance gain it could bring.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to find out yourself? Random list access should be `O(1)` (I guess), so I don't see the benefit.

Comment: It would be a major change because the script is already quite complex, therefore I am looking for input before investing in those changes. If there is no benefit to be expected, it will safe me the hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List access takes O(1) time. So, there is no need to assign it to a variable.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!